# Unable to Copy artifacts from github inside docker image during build stage in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, devops

I am developing simple DevOps CICD pipeline using Azure pipeline.

I am using a Dockerfile placed in GitHub repo to build Docker image during build stage. when I build a image I want to all files in that directory (BuildtsagingDirectory) inside Docker image.

Need advice on how can I achieve that.

I tried publish & setting context but unable to copy files inside docker image.

appreciate your quick response Thanks a lot

Comment: Two things: is *BuildtsagingDirectory* a typo? and have you tried mounting the directory?

Comment: Hi @THBBFT, I have set  buildContext: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and  published using 
 - publish: $(artifact_path)
  artifact: dkp-ellipse-backend
But i was just thinking how will these published artifacts be copied in image as Azure will be using Dockerfile .. and how can i inject these files inside from azure pipeline
I have mapped the docker image to volume using pvc as I want to use this docker image in kubernetes cluster with docker image having required artifacts to run before  it is deployed